# Undefined index: params in CRM_Event_BAO_Event::buildCustomProfile() - CiviEvent

Tags: civievent, civicontribute, error

I just came across this error (that I'd just like to clean up) after cancelling my PayPal transaction and returning to my site:

Undefined index: params in CRM_Event_BAO_Event::buildCustomProfile()

Are there any fixes for this issue?

Thanks! Matt

Answer (score 2):

I also came across this notice, I've submitted a pull request: https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/12678